# How to access ng-model from attribute directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to write a custom directive to validate input value: does it belong to the specified range. The problem is that I can't access `ng-model` without knowing the name of the scope variable which is used for `ng-model`. Considering that directive has to be reused with different inputs I want to access `ng-model` directly. I did try to use `scope[attrs.ngModel]` but got the `undefined` value. How can read `ng-model` value inside directive? Thank you.

```
netupApp.directive('between', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        scope.$watch('dataSubmitting', function(dataSubmitting){
            if (dataSubmitting) {
                var min = Number(attrs.min);
                var max = Number(attrs.max);
                console.log(attrs.ngModel); // "number"
                console.log(scope[attrs.ngModel]); // undefined
                var inputText = scope.number; // that is the var used in ng-model
                console.log(min); // 10
                console.log(inputText); // would be the input value
                console.log(max); //20
                if (inputText <= min || inputText >= max) {
                    scope.alerts.push({
                        msg: 'error',
                        type: 'danger',
                        icon: 'warning',
                        'closable': true
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to access scope anyway (because you don't)?

Comment: @dfsq Maybe there is a better solution, I don't know :) I have to write some custom directives to validate input values, they should check the values after the submit action (there is no form, just inputs), and push the alert msg to the scope's alerts array.

Comment: Well ideal directive would not need to know anything about scope, names, etc. It would also not need to manage error messages, those should be a responsibility of controller/template. Directive should not decide whether there is error or not. What directive must do though is to just check what validity state is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hook into the Angular validation system and add your validator function to either the $validators or $asyncValidators collections (in your case I think $validators is enough, no need for async).

The validator functions receive the model value as an argument :

```
link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

    var min = Number(attrs.min);
    var max = Number(attrs.max);

    ctrl.$validators.between = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (modelValue <= min || modelValue >= max) {
            //do something here or just return false
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

In the view you can get the validation error messages like this :

```
<div ng-messages="formName.inputName.$error">
    <p ng-message="between">The value is not in the required range<p>
</div>
```

Reference doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Comment: Thanks. Would mark this one as the accepted answer, because it advises better (proper) solution.

Comment: Thanks! Sure, why reinvent the wheel when there already is a mechanism baked-in for validation ?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to get the `ngModel.$viewValue` is:

```
app.directive('between', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        ngModel.$render = function () {
            var newValue = ngModel.$viewValue;
            console.log(newValue)
        };

    }
  };
});
```

Have a look at tutorial underneath when wanting to invoke the `ngModel.$setViewVAlue` from the `directive`

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-ngmodel-in-custom-directives

Comment: Thanks. I saw this tutorial but wasn't able to get the result, maybe there were some problems with initialization, now everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

According to angluarJs doc:[$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse)
you need to parse the attrs, please try:

```
var getter=$parse(attrs.ngModel);
var setter=getter.assign;
setter(scope,getter(scope));
```

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but I think it's more of a dirty trick, don't think this has to be the default solution. Thank you for your help!